# Problem with access to Microsoft graph using Web API and MS Graph SDK in c#

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

Recently I'm trying to connect to Microsoft Graph using Web API app in C#.
This is Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
       .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
       .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
       .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

appseettings.json

```
{
   "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "Domain": "******",
        "TenantId": "******",
        "ClientId": "******",
        "ClientCapabilities": [ "cp1" ],
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
        "Scopes": "user.read",
        "ClientSecret": "*********",
        "ClientCertificates": []
    },
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

namespace ZapaGraph.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class GraphController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

        public GraphController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
        {
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        }

        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "MicrosoftGraph:Scopes")]
        [HttpGet("GetData")]
        public async void Get()
        {
            var user = await _graphServiceClient.Users["*****"].Request().GetAsync();
            
        }
    }
}
```

This code it's not working because, I'm not authorized and access token it's not stored in application.

I tried to authorize manually before each call to Microsoft Graph and it's work:

```
 TokenCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
     _configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"],
     _configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"],
     _configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"]);
 graphServiceClient.AuthenticationProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(clientSecretCredential);
var user = await graphServiceClient.Users["*****"].Request().GetAsync();
```

And here's my question. Is any way to Authorize automatically e.g. in Program.cs and skip a step with manually get TokenCredential?

I looked for some tutorials but everywhere working without set  graphServiceClient.AuthenticationProvider. Also when I connect to ms Graph using Visual Studio it's not working and generated code looks voery similar.[connect to MS Graph using visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAFwl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSAL caches a token after it's been acquired. The app should first try to get a token silently from the cache before attempting to acquire a token by other means.

1. Here is a link to guide on how this can be achieved
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens.
2. Here are 2 samples code that will be helpful:

   web app - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-
   webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph

   daemon - (This is an easy guide to understand the concept) https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph

   web API - (assuming OnBehalfOf Flow )
   https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof